# Create a dictionary in a dictionary and find the max value in python 3.x

Tags: python, dictionary

csv file:[csv file](https://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse231/Projects/Project05/alltablesGEcrops.csv)

I have a csv data file with state names and crop types and different values. I want to create a dictionary in a dictionary such that the output looks like

```
{'Corn': {'Illinois': ['93']}}
{'Soybeans': {'Illinois': ['94']}}
```

where {'crop type':{'state':['max_value']}}.

Here is my current code:

```
STATES = ['Alaska', 'Alabama', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming']

def open_file():
    fp = open('alltablesGEcrops.csv', 'r')
    return fp

def read_file(fp):
    fp.readline()
    dict1 = {}
    dict2 = {}
    for line in fp:
        line_lst = line.strip().split(',')
        state = line_lst[0]
        crop = line_lst[1]
        variety = line_lst[3]
        year = int(line_lst[4])
        value = line_lst[6]
        if variety == 'All GE varieties' and state == 'Illinois':
            max_value = max(value, key=int)
            dict1.setdefault(state,[]).append(max_value)
            dict2 = {crop:dict1}
            print(dict2)

def main():
    fp = open_file()
    data = read_file(fp)
    print(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Its output looks like this:
[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI9xV.png)

I am wondering how can I fix my code so that I could only print out the last line for each crop type? Also, when I find the max value, it always print out

```
{'Soybeans': {'Illinois': ['7', '6', '2', '8', '3', '6', '5', '7', ...]}}
```

instead of

```
{'Soybeans': {'Illinois': ['94']}}
```

How could I fix that?

Comment: not seeing in your code where you are looking for the max, also what does `'alltablesGEcrops.csv'` look like, provide sample data....

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy I am sorry about that, I have just edited my code.

Comment: thats your problem, you say `value` is equal to some value then check the max of that and append it to a list as opposed to checking the max value of the list you are appending to

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy OK! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without Pandas, but why would you want to?

```
import pandas as pd

# load dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('alltablesGEcrops.csv', na_values={"Value": ("*", ".")})

# produce results
print(df.groupby(['State', 'Crop'])['Value'].max())
```

which gives

```
State           Crop
Alabama         Upland cotton    98
Arkansas        Soybeans         99
                Upland cotton    99
California      Upland cotton     9
Georgia         Upland cotton    99
Illinois        Corn             93
                Soybeans         94
Indiana         Corn              9
                Soybeans         96
Iowa            Corn             95
                Soybeans         97
Kansas          Corn             95
                Soybeans         96
Louisiana       Upland cotton    99
Michigan        Corn             93
                Soybeans         95
Minnesota       Corn             93
                Soybeans         96
Mississippi     Soybeans         99
                Upland cotton    99
Missouri        Corn             93
                Soybeans         94
Missouri 2/     Upland cotton    99
Nebraska        Corn             96
                Soybeans         97
North Carolina  Upland cotton    98
North Dakota    Soybeans         98
North Dakota    Corn             97
Ohio            Corn              9
                Soybeans         91
Other States    Corn             91
                Soybeans         94
                Upland cotton    98
South Dakota    Corn             98
                Soybeans         98
Tennessee       Upland cotton    99
Texas           Upland cotton    93
Texas           Corn             91
U.S.            Corn             93
                Soybeans         94
                Upland cotton    96
Wisconsin       Corn             92
                Soybeans         95
Name: Value, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this just using a dictionary:

```
 from collections import defaultdict

f = open('alltablesGEcrops.csv').readlines()

f = [i.strip('\n').split(',') for i in f]

d = defaultdict(dict)


for i in f[1:]:
    if i[0] in d[i[1]].keys():

        if i[-1] > max(d[i[1]][i[0]]):

            d[i[1]][i[0]] = [i[-1]]

     else:
         d[i[1]][i[0]] = [i[-1]]

print dict(d)
```